# Repeating Formula Excel

Tags: excel

I am currently working on a large data file and I want to have a repetitive formula all 12 rows.

Currently I am using the following function:

Repeating Formula Excel

```
=(((ROWS(C2:C13)/3)/4)INDEX($D2:$D63128,(ROWS($D2:$D2)-1)*12+1))
```

The first argument is my formula and the second part is my try to repeat it.
In the first row is a column name. Therefore I begin from row 2. Also the formula should be repeated from row 2 to 63128 in a 12 row interval.

This is the data set i am working with: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0By2vKtmbq9s2dlJaVXNFVENkYkE It is a fairly large data set and I am currently in the process of cleaning it.

Comment: Why not simply `=IF(MOD(ROW(),12)=2,[your formula],"")`?

Answer (score 0):

Enter your formula as you want it in the first 12 rows, then select exactly those 12 rows and choose Fill Down.

Comment: I want to have the calculation in a 12 weeks interval (per Quarter), but sometimes there are some weeks missing. Hence if i do that the calculation would be wrong.

Comment: Can you post some sample data or a screenshot?  It is really difficult to see what you are asking.

Comment: Google Docs says it can't open that link :(

Comment: [Data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0By2vKtmbq9s2b1RfTVMzR0s2T3c/view?usp=sharing) This should work :)